# Why is the cls keyword attribute reserved when using typing.Generic in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy

How is it that the `Generic` class (I'll be using Python 3.7+ [PEP-0560](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0560/)), restricts the use of `cls` as a keyword argument in `__init__` ?

This is pretty clear:

```
>>> from typing import Generic, TypeVar
>>> I = TypeVar("I")
>>> class A(Generic[I]):
...     def __init__(self, cls=1):
...         pass
... 
>>> A(1)  # No error
>>> A(cls=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __new__() got multiple values for argument 'cls'
```

This looks like something specific to `Generic`. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/68874a8502da440a1dc4746cf73262648b870aee/Lib/typing.py#L897):

```
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwds):
        if cls in (Generic, Protocol):
            raise TypeError(f"Type {cls.__name__} cannot be instantiated; "
                            "it can be used only as a base class")
        if super().__new__ is object.__new__ and cls.__init__ is not object.__init__:
            obj = super().__new__(cls)
        else:
            obj = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwds)
        return obj
```

Here we can see it uses `cls` as the name, so you cannot pass another one in the `**kwds`.